# Глюки preg_replace

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Необходимо по известной ссылке получить абсолютный путь к файлу на сервере. Реализую это следующим образом:

```
$image = preg_replace("/^http.*/{2}[^/]*/i", $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT],        "http://example.com/image.jpg");
```

При выполнении этого кода `$image` принимает значение `null`, хотя по идее там должен быть полный путь к файлу. `preg_last_error` говорит что ни каких ошибок не возникло. Даже не знаю что может быть не так в одной строке кода...

Comment: Ваша регулярка в адресе  

    http://example.com/folder//image.jpg
приведет к нехорошему результату.  

    .*
захватит весь текст до конца строки, потом вернется назад до первого `//` от конца строки, и [^\/]* захватит все до image.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужно экранировать слэши, если используете слэш как разделитель.
Вместо точки лучше поставить двоеточие. Точка это любой символ.
Вот так работает как надо.

```
$image = preg_replace("/^https?:\/\/[^\/]*/i", $_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT], "http://example.com/image.jpg");
```

Comment: в данном случае лучше было бы использовать другой разделитель) Регулярка лучше читается)

Comment: @shurik, тут мне кажется дело привычки. Я всегда например использую слэши, и когда вижу разделители !@#{} в чужих регулярках, то они сначала вызывают у меня ступор секунд на 5 :)

Comment: Спасибо, работает. А потребность экранировать слэши это особенность php? Или на все регулярные выражения распространяется? Ещё я почему-то думал, что если с регуляркой что-то не так, то `preg_last_error` должен возвратить ошибку.